# Criar uma dimensão calendário com o mês anterior ao do Sys.date

Tags: r, data, data.frame

Olá, o scrip abaixo cria uma CSV com uma dimensão Calendário do ano de 2015 até o mês atual. Ocorre que eu gostaria que a função retornasse o mês anterior ao da execução. Ex: Se o Sys.Data registra 14/11/2017, ele retornasse a data 14/10/2017.
Ou, se possível, a data 01/10/2017, já que o dia 01 é o padrão nessa dCalendário. 
OBS: Se preferirem, podem sugerir a criação de outro script

```
        tabela_tcm_dCalendario <- list(mes = 1:12, ano = 2015:2017) %>% 
                              purrr::cross_df() %>% 
                              dplyr::mutate(data = as.Date(sprintf("%d-%02d-01", ano, mes))) %>%
                              dplyr::filter(data < Sys.Date())
                              readr::write_csv("parametros_scraping/tabela_tcm_dCalendario.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue fazer assim:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data_frame(
  data = seq(ymd("2015-01-01"), (today() - day(today()) + 1 - months(1)), by = "month"),
  ano = year(data),
  mes = month(data)
)
```

Veja que a parte `(today() - day(today()) + 1 ) - months(1)` retorna o primeiro dia do mês anterior. A partir disso, usei a função `seq` para criar uma sequência de datas a partir de janeiro de 2015.

Comment: Muito Obrigado. O script está excelente. Acabei substituindo o meu. Essa parte final, confesso que ainda terei que estudar mais um pouco para compreender. Estou iniciando no R tem cerca de 1 mês.

Answer (score 3):

Adicionei a função `slice` no seu código

```
list(mes = 1:12, ano = 2015:2017) %>% 
  purrr::cross_df() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(data = as.Date(sprintf("%d-%02d-01", ano, mes))) %>%
  dplyr::filter(data < Sys.Date()) %>% 
  dplyr::slice(1:(nrow(.)-1))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. A sugestão foi muito boa